# How many ways are there to seat in a row four boys and four girls if (variation of another problem)

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to seat in a row four boys and four girls
if

1)At least two girls are seated together?

2)There must be only two girls together?

For the first, I proceeded as follows

_A_A_A_A_A_A_

There are 7 places to put the group of two girls, where A is equal to B (boy) or G (girl), in other words, the genre does not matter.

n. ways = ${5}\choose{1} $ $2!6!$

Is that correct?

For the second item, I have no idea

Thanks!

P.S. English isn't my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: For the first question, the best approach is to subtract the number of arrangements in which no two girls are seated together from the total number of arrangements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many ways are there to seat four boys and four girls in a row if at least two girls are seated together?

There are $8!$ ways to arrange the eight children.  From these, we subtract those arrangements in which no girls are seated together.

Arrange the four boys in a row.  This creates five spaces, three between successive boys and two at the ends of the row.

$$\square B \square B \square B \square B \square$$

To ensure that no two girls are adjacent, we must choose four of these five spaces.  Finally, we arrange the girls in the chosen spaces.  Thus, the number of prohibited seating arrangements is

$$4!\binom{5}{4}4! = 4!5!$$

so the number of permissible seating arrangements is

$$8! - 4!5!$$

> How many ways are there to seat four boys and four girls in a row if there must be only two girls together?

Strategy:

1. Arrange the boys.
2. In the spaces created by the boys, choose one for the pair of girls who will sit together.
3. Choose two of the remaining spaces for the other two girls.
4. Arrange the girls in the three spaces you have selected.

Comment: Thank you so much!. Hence for the second question, we have 4! $5 \choose 1$ $4 \choose 2$ $2! * 1 * 1$ possible ways. But, also could I choose 3 three spaces for arranging the three subsets from the group of girls with 2, 1 and 1 elements respectively?

Comment: For the second problem, we have $4!$ ways of arranging the boys, $\binom{5}{1}$ ways of choosing the space for the two girls, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing two spaces where one girl each will be placed, and $4!$ ways of arranging the girls from left to right in the selected spaces.  Hence, the number of permissible arrangements is $$4!\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}4!$$  If you choose three spaces first, then you have to select which of them will be filled with two girls.  $$4!\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{1}4!$$  Either method is valid.